# Get Host Name with Curl using ip

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way to get the host name using CURL, or what is the preferred way using PHP?

Comment: Like if you were to do an ip lookup on an ip address. I am looking for the host name.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand… What is your expected input and output?

Comment: @Mike yeah, please make an example.

Comment: gethostbyaddr is the function to use. Sorry for the confusion. There is curl in the script so I had curl on the mind. Nice to know about this new function...

Comment: Still, your question is not clear. It seems (by the answer you suggested yourself) you were looking for a **reverse DNS lookup (i.e. finding an hostname by IP), using PHP.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do this in curl. Just use the [gethostbyaddr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) function.

```
echo gethostbyaddr('1.2.3.4');
```

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to experiment without using cURL.

Try looking at: [gethostbyname();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) and [gethostbyaddr();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php)

Basicly:

1. Get host IP address by using `gethostbyname();`
2. Fetch host name by using `gethostbyaddr();` with previously fetched IP address.

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
$host = gethostbyaddr($ip);

echo $host;
```

Just tested it, and — works, plus, you don't have to know targeted host's IP address.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need cURL for this. [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) does a reverse DNS lookup. I believe that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be gotten with $_SERVER, specifically $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: That's the host of the server. He probably wants to find out other hosts, not his own.